# TrueCrypt: Open volume without mounting

Tags: macos, truecrypt

I have a corrupt TrueCrypt volume. When I try to mount it, the password is fine but I get an error: `hdiutil attach failed no mountable file systems.`

I just need to open it without TrueCrypt trying to mount it too, so I can use that partition in a data recovery program. Also it's just an image file volume. I have read the documentation here:
http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=command-line-usage

But I can't figure out which switch I need to use to only open an image and not mount it.

I am using the Mac version, and I have set up an alias for the TrueCrypt shell command, so I can just type:

```
truecrypt -t -v - ?? [][]..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mounting with `--filesystem=none`:

```
--filesystem=TYPE
 Filesystem type to mount. The TYPE argument is passed to mount(8) command
 with option -t. Default type is 'auto'. When creating a new volume, this
 option specifies the filesystem to be created on the new volume (only 'FAT'
 and 'none' TYPE is allowed). Filesystem type 'none' disables mounting or
 creating a filesystem.`
```

Note that this is from the documentation of TrueCrypt 7.1a on Ubuntu but I guess that it works also on a Mac.

On Windows, the corresponsing parameter is `/m recovery`.

In general, if you encounter problems while mounting, you can try the option `-m headerbak` (Linux/Mac) or `/m headerbak` (Windows) first to have TrueCrypt using a backup of the volume header instead of the original (possibly damaged) volume header. Backup volume headers are available since TrueCrypt version 6.0.